# change to directory after searching for the file via DIR

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Outcome is to change to directory after searching for the file via DIR through cmd

Location of file is C:\Folder

is the following code possible?

```
set /a variable= dir document.doc /s /p

cd %%variable%%
```

Change directory to C:\Folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('dir document.doc /s /b') do (
  set "new_dir=%%~dp#"
)

cd /d "%new_dir%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the output help carefully from first to last page.
`set /A` is for evaluating an **arithmetic expression**. So the string after `set /A` is interpreted by Windows command line interpreter as arithmetic expression (formula).

```
set /a variable= dir document.doc /s /p
```

This command line outputs on execution the error message `missing operator` because `dir` is interpreted as a variable name and also `document.doc` both most likely not existing and therefore replaced by `0` on evaluating the expression. But `cmd.exe` expects an operator between those two environment variable names and as there is none like `/` before variable `s`, the error message is output.

It is not possible to assign possible multi-line output of a command line like `dir document.doc /s /p` to an environment variable with command **SET**.

In a batch file you can use this code:

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in ("document*.doc") do cd /D "%%~dpI" & goto FoundFile
echo Could not find any document*.doc in %CD% or its subdirectories.
pause
goto :EOF

:FoundFile
echo Found a file document*.doc in directory %CD%.
pause
```

Command **FOR** searches for any non hidden file matching the pattern `document*.doc` in current directory and all non hidden subdirectories. A wildcard character like `*` or `?` must be specified to run a search for a file. If a file is found, the command **CD** is executed to change to directory of the file and the loop is exited with a jump to a label.

Another solution to really search only for file `document.doc`:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "document*.doc" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do cd /D "%%~dpI" & goto FoundFile
echo Could not find file document.doc in %CD% or its subdirectories.
pause
goto :EOF

:FoundFile
echo Found file document.doc in directory %CD%.
pause
```

This example shows how to run a command line like `dir "document*.doc" /A-D /B /S 2>nul` in a separate command process started by **FOR** with `cmd.exe /C` with capturing all output lines written to handle **STDOUT** while in this case redirecting an error message written to handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it.

The captured output is next processed by **FOR** line by line with skipping with default options all empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon and splitting up each line into substrings (tokens) using space and tab as delimiters with assigning only first substring to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is disabled by using `"delims="` which defines an empty list of delimiters and so no line splitting is possible anymore. In this case it is impossible that a line output by **DIR** starts with `;` and so we don't need to care about `eol` (end of line) option.

`%%~dpI` expanding to just drive and path of current file name with path can be also assigned to an environment variable for example with `set "FilePath=%%~dpI"`. And the environment variable `FilePath` can be referenced in rest of the batch file either with immediate expansion using `%FilePath%` or with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) using `!FilePath!` enclosed the entire argument string containing this variable reference in double quotes for working also for file paths containing a space or one of these characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

Both batch codes always changes to **first** found `document*.doc` respectively `document.doc` file and ignoring all other files matching the pattern respectively with same name perhaps also found by **FOR** or **DIR** in other directories in searched directory tree. The first solution is faster on a large directory tree needs to be searched for the file. But first solution ignores hidden subdirectories and can change to a directory containing for example `document_1.doc` instead of `document.doc`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.