# Not able to print string through echo

Tags: batch-file, echo

not able to print %%# from batch

```
echo for /f 'delims=' %%# in ('dir doc1.docx /s /b') do ( >> C:\test.bat
  echo set 'file=%%~dp#' >> C:\test.bat 
echo ) >> C:\test.bat
```

expected result

```
for /f 'delims=' %%# in ('dir doc1.docx /s /b') do ( 
    set 'file=%%~dp#' >> C:\test.bat 
)
```

continuation from 
[change to directory after searching for the file via DIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138643/change-to-directory-after-searching-for-the-file-via-dir)

Comment: you just echo a string and didn't run any commands. and what do you think a missing parentheses do `( >> C:\test.bat`?

Comment: i have rephrased the question to the sample code

Comment: Please review [ASK] and [MCVE].  So, you are trying to build a script file using the echo command?  What result are you getting from the above? Probably missing a percent symbol perhaps?

Comment: I can almost guarantee there is a better solution to whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. Using batch to write batch code is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to escape the percent symbols:

```
echo for /f 'delims=' %%%%# in ('dir doc1.docx /s /b') do ( >> test2.bat
```

Comment: it doesnt print as the expected result

result gets cascaded

Comment: i have put expected result

Answer (score 0):

Escape opening braces `(` and any redirection symbols `<>` with `^` thus making those characters literal. You could probably do closing braces `)` as
well for certainty.

Percentage signs are escaped by doubling them up so `%` becomes `%%`.

```
echo for /f 'delims=' %%%%# in ^('dir doc1.docx /s /b'^) do ^(
echo     set 'file=%%~dp#' ^>^> C:\test.bat
echo ^)
```

Outputs:

```
for /f 'delims=' %%# in ('dir doc1.docx /s /b') do (
    set 'file=%~dp#' >> C:\test.bat
)
```

Though I advise double quoting to be used in some places and I am going
to guess that you want to write this `for` loop to test.bat. Typically `C:\`
is protected from write by UAC so I will do a relative write.

```
(   echo for /f "delims=" %%%%# in ^('dir doc1.docx /s /b'^) do ^(
    echo     set "file=%%~dp#"
    echo ^)
) >> .\test.bat
```

Outputs:

```
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('dir doc1.docx /s /b') do (
    set "file=%~dp#"
)
```

Comment: You only need to escape closing brackets (only if you are inside a code block), opening brackets never creates problems